# Javascript listener triggers on child of the event target, not the actual element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript event handler that is not getting me the attributes I need. Here is my situation.

I have an HMTL DOM similar to the following:

```
<div id='section-header'>
    <a href="#anchor1">
        <img src="path/to/an/image1.png">
    </a>
    <a href="#anchor2">
        <img src="path/to/an/image2.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

I am instantiating my event listener like so:

```
var aList = document.getElementById('section-header').getElementsByTagName('a');

var anchorScroll = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = event.target.attributes;
    console.log("target: ", target);
};

for (var i = 0;i < aList.length;i++) {
    aList[i].addEventListener('click', anchorScroll, false);
}
```

When I click on one of the images, the event function is fired, however the target element is the image, not the `a` tag. Thus, the `attributes` object does not have an `href` key-value pair, and I need that `href`. Instead, the attributes object only has an `src` key-value pair.

Why is the `a` element not the target of this event? How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the initial target of the event will be the `img`, since it's the innermost element that was clicked on. To distinguish between it and the element the event handler is actually bound to, the `Event` object has both `target` and `currentTarget` properties:

> (`currentTarget`) [i]dentifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Or you may simply use `this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation to capture all the clicks within section-header, then determine what action to take based on the tag name.

```js
var anchorScroll = (event) => {
  var link;
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    link = event.target.parentNode;
   
  } else {
    link = event.target;
  }
  console.log("target: " + link);
};
document.getElementById('section-header').addEventListener('click', anchorScroll);
```

```html
<div id='section-header'>
  <a href="#anchor1">
    <img src="path/to/an/image1.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#anchor2">
    <img src="path/to/an/image2.png">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: While this is a solution, the use of `parentNode` makes your response an indirect answer for my problem.

Comment: This tightly couples the event handler to the specific HTML used, i.e. it requires an `img` and that its parent is an `a`. This makes the markup very inflexible…

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment - your second question was 'how do I remedy this' - which is what I focused on.  Good question

Comment: @deceze - yes - a more elegant solution would be to traverse up the tree until an HREF attribute is found

Comment: @user2182349 Understood. Deceze more eloquently summed up my concerns.