# Getting value as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using ReactJs. In useEffect I'm fetching the values from the database and storing them in an images state.
While mapping these values I'm giving the 'sno' value to each button. Now when I click on the trash button I'm printing the value of the button. As per the expectations, I should get the exact sno value always but sometimes undefined is getting printed.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './addphotos.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faCheck } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import AdditionTemplate from "./AdditionTemplate";
import Instance from "../Axios/Instance";
const AddPhotos = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchImages();
    }, []);
    async function fetchImages() {
        const result = await Instance.get('/photos/getImages');
        setImages(result.data);
    }
    images.shift();
    console.log(images);
    const handleDelete = async (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value); 
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="grid mt-5 w-75">
                {
                    images.map((pic) => {
                        return (
                            <ul key={pic.SNO}>
                                <img src={`http://localhost:1200/Images/getImages/${pic.NAME}`} alt={`${pic.PIC_NAME}`}
                                />
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <button value={pic.SNO} className="btn text-danger" onClick = {(e)=>handleDelete(e)}>
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        )
                    })
                }
                <div>
                    <AdditionTemplate />
                </div>
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default AddPhotos;
```

What is the exact problem? If possible please explain in detail.

Comment: Please also share an example of the images data?

Comment: what is the point of `images.shift();`?

Comment: `console.log(e.currentTarget.value);` target when you click on the trash can will be the trashcan, not the button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970236/javascript-listener-triggers-on-child-of-the-event-target-not-the-actual-elemen

Comment: I know you already have an answer, but please read [ask], especially the section on writing titles. The current title says very little about the specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `handleDelete` to the following:

```
const handleDelete = async (sno) => {
    console.log(sno); // Accessing the `sno` value directly
}
```

and update the `<button>` to the following:

```
<button
   className="btn text-danger"
   onClick={() => handleDelete(pic.SNO)} // Pass `pic.SNO` as an argument
>
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
</button>
```

Comment: incorrect reasoning in this case

Comment: Hello @dan_pran, Yes It is working now as expected. Thank you